# Aligning components and buttons within components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have two React Components, `Open` and `Save`. The `Save` component contains an `saveButton`. The `Open` component contains an `openButton`, along with a `stopButton` and `executeButton` that shows up depending on the state of the component. I want my `Open` and `Save` components to be lined up next to each other, on the same row:

```
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row}}>
    <Save></Save>
    <Open></Open>
</div>
```

The initial state looks like this:

[image: init]

The state where all four buttons show look like this:

[image: allStates]

Remember that Execute and Stop are part of the same `Open` component that contains the Open button. How can I align the components so that the Save/Open buttons are aligned all the way to the left, and the Execute/Stop buttons are aligned all the way to the right?

For clarification, I want the buttons formatted like this:

`Save Open ------------all whitespace here--------------- Execute Stop`

Edit: Here is the (very simplified) code for the components

```
// Save 

<Button>Save</Button>

//Open
this.state = { executeFlag: false, stopFlag: false}
render(){
    let stop;
    let execute;
    if(this.state.stopFlag) stopButton = <Button>Stop</Button>;
    if(this.state.executeFlag) executeButton = <Button>Execute</Button>;
    return(
        <div>
            <Button>Open</Button>{execute}{stop}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Any reason my answer does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your css maybe you could try setting the width of the buttons to 50% each and margin to zero. I believe flex will display on the same row as long as they can fit.

Comment: I added a clarification to my post above. Would do this make the buttons take up the entire width of the screen?

Comment: The entire width of the containing div. however that divs width can also be set so it only takes up as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that... It really depends on the structure of your component and not just the control buttons. Here is a sample structure I usually use for something similar in plain HTML CSS for your reference

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.component-b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sub-menu{
  display: flex;
  justofy-content: flex-end;
}

.button {
  background: #1E88E5;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="component-a button">
      Save
    </div>
    <div class="component-b">
      <div class="button">
        Open
      </div>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <div class="button">
          Execute
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          Stop
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by wrapping two components set in one div and then wrapping all in div and using flex properties

```
<div style={{
   display:'flex'
   justifyContent:'space-between',
   aligItems:'center'
    }}
>
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row',justifyConetent:'space-around'}}>
    <Save></Save>
    <Open></Open>
</div>
<div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row',justifyConetent:'space-around'}}>
    <Execute></Execute>
    <Stop></Stop>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Main computer isn't on me right now so I can't try it out, but `Execute` and `Stop` are not their own components. I'll add some more detail to the original post so you can take a look

Comment: I added the source code for the components so you could take a closer look at them